# Python 3.x Need help applying math functions to a 1D array using map()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am reading a Python programming book. The author said that the `map` function was one way to apply math package functions such as `sqrt` to elements in a 1D array. I followed the book's instructions and ran the following code:

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import array
a = array([4,9,16],float)
b = array(map(sqrt,a),float)
print(b)
```

Instead of the expected `[2.0 3.0 4.0]`, the console displayed
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'`

I also tried with the numpy `sqrt`; however, the console displayed the same error.

How can I improve  my code to apply these elementary functions to my arrays?

I would appreciate any constructive criticism since I am new to stackoverflow and programming in general.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using numpy arrays? `map` is more usseful when working on lists. Most numpy functions already have a map-like behaviour, for example the numpy function `numpy.sqrt` will return an array of the square root of all the input array's numbers

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo. I am following a programming book, and this is how the author preferred to work with arrays. It is weird they did not mention this since the book also works with numpy functions. I will now use numpy functions when working with arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is that `map` returns a `map` object, and not a `list`, which is what I believe you want.

You could just cast it to list like so:

```py
b = array(list(map(sqrt, a)), float)
```

Of course this is only because you wanted to use the `map` function, you could always just do:

```py
import numpy as np
b = np.sqrt(a)
```

Hope that helped =).